# xbar y-axis labels are blank for every other bar

Tags: pgfplots

Code produces a horizontal bar chart where the name ("a", "b", etc.) for each bar only appears for every other bar. The number of bars (10) seems to trigger the issue; removing one of the bars solves the issue. But obviously I need 10 bars

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[title  = Figure 1,
    xbar,
    y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
        axis x line*=bottom,
    tickwidth         = 0pt,
        xmin=0,
        /pgf/bar width=18pt,
        width=.75\textwidth, 
      symbolic y coords = {a,
                b,
                c,
                d,
                e,
                f,
                g,
                h,
                i, 
                j },
   nodes near coords,
  ]
  \addplot coordinates {(14,a) 
                (15,b)
                (16,c)
                (16,d)
                (17,e)
                (21,f)
                (21,g)
                (30,h)
                (34,i)
                (34,j)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Adding `ytick distance=1,` seems to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

Pgfplots has its on means to decide what a useful density of ticks and so on is. In most cases, the decision leads to an appealing output. Yet sometimes one has to override the decisions made by `pgfplots`. On way to do so is to set the distance between the ticks. In your case, it seems to suffice to say `ytick distance=1`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[title  = Figure 1,
    xbar,
    y axis line style = { opacity = 0 },
        axis x line*=bottom,
    tickwidth         = 0pt,
        xmin=0,
        /pgf/bar width=18pt,
        width=.75\textwidth,ytick distance=1,
      symbolic y coords = {a,
                b,
                c,
                d,
                e,
                f,
                g,
                h,
                i, 
                j },
   nodes near coords,
  ]
  \addplot coordinates {(14,a) 
                (15,b)
                (16,c)
                (16,d)
                (17,e)
                (21,f)
                (21,g)
                (30,h)
                (34,i)
                (34,j)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Attached to the answer comes the request to consider providing complete minimal working examples in your posts, i.e. documents like the above which start with `\documentclass`, end with `\end{document}`, can be compiled and contain just enough to illustrate the issue. It is quite conceivable that the code for the tikzpicture behaves differently in different document classes, as e.g. `\textwidth` depends on them.

Comment: Thank you! I thought it would be something simple.

Answer (score 1):

Except if you want to this some showy add-on, for a simple horizontal bar plot I suggest the simple and easy `bchart` package.  Only a  few options available, but enough for a clean and elegant result.

However, the MWE show unnecessary and inelegant colorful plot in order to show how you can customize the some parts of the plot beside of these options.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\newcounter{ylab}\setcounter{ylab}{0}
\usepackage{bchart}\renewcommand{\bcfontstyle}{\color{green!30!black}}
\def\xbar#1{\color{darkgray}\stepcounter{ylab}%
\bcbar[label=\color{red!70!black}\alph{ylab},%
value=\textcolor{blue!#1!blue!70}{#1},color=blue!#1]{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{bchart}[step=5,max=35,scale=1,width=.5\linewidth]
\xbar{34}
\xbar{30}
\xbar{21}
\xbar{17}
\xbar{16}
\xbar{16}
\xbar{15}
\xbar{14}
\xbar{9}
\xbar{17}
\end{bchart}

\end{document}
```